# Realm versioned objects

Tags: android, ios, realm

**TL;DR:** we are looking for a pattern of implementing "versioned" objects in Realm, so the "last" version is accessible fast (just by primary key), and creating a "historical" version from "last" version before updating is easy, as well as accessing all old versions of the object.

Some background.

We are implementing Realm as a replacement for SQLite in Android app and also "from scratch" in iOS app. We have a unified backend for both apps and want to keep the Realm object representation as close as possible between platforms.

In SQLite, we have 2 tables with basically the same structure, one having the last version of each object, and the second - all previous versions. Before updating the "main" table, we copy the row-to-be-updated to the "history" table and then do the update.

Comment: Sounds like something that _might_ be possible using [Realm Functions](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#realm-functions). Have you taken a look there yet?

Comment: @AviWarner these are realm object server features, we are not using them.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, the only option I can think of is to

> have 2 tables with basically the same structure, one having the last version of each object, and the second - all previous versions.

The key difference would be that the history table has no primary key (or it is constructed from concating original primary key with version number).

```
public class Dog extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String dogId;

    @Index
    private String dogName;

    private int version;
}

public class DogHistory extends RealmObject {
    private String dogId; // decide if primary key from dogId+version is needed

    @Index
    private String dogName;

    private int version;
}
```

And then map them over.

```
DogHistory dogHistory = new DogHistory(); 
dogHistory.setDogId(currentDog.getDogId());
dogHistory.setDogName(currentDog.getDogName());
dogHistory.setVersion(currentDog.getVersion());
realm.insert(dogHistory); //not "insertOrUpdate" if no PK field
```

The tricky thing is that you'd only be able to see them as "the same object" if you expose the getters/setters via interface. Or you map them back to `Dog`, but it will become an unmanaged instance then.

Comment: I am not sure how inheritance and polymorphism work in Realm, but was thinking in the following direction:
```class DogData {
...
}

class Dog extends DogData { ... }

class DogHistory extends DogData { ... }
```

Here `DogData` holds meaningful fields, while subclasses basically differ in terms of primary keys.

Comment: You cannot extend anything if you're using a RealmObject class, and you specifically cannot inherit fields between RealmObjects. Hence why I said that mapping is easier than exposing all getters/setters in a shared interface (although I had to do that before and it worked)